# Get-ADGroup with -recursive is not working?

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am using `get-adgroupmember` command to fetch all the users in an AD group. `-recursive` is helping me fetch members from child groups if any in the parent group as well.

However, `get-adgroupmember` has an upper limit of 5000 entries only.

To tackle this if i use:

```
Get-ADGroup -Identity "DEPT_120_SA" -server "A" -Properties * | select-object -expandproperty members |get-aduser
```

this doesnt work as my Parent AD has child ADs and `-recursive` is not accepted by `get-adgroup`.

Error:

> Get-ADGroup : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name
>   'recursive'. At line:2 char:79
>   + Get-ADGroup -Identity "DEPT_120_SA" -server "mhf.mhc" -Properties * -recursive <<<<  | select-object -expandproperty members
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-ADGroup], ParameterBindingException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADGroup

my aim is to display username and their mail iDS and this works for me:

```
Get-ADGroupMember -server $domain -identity $s -Recursive -ErrorAction Stop | Get-AdUser -Properties mail -ErrorAction Stop | select sAmAccountName, Mail
```

Any workaround ? (I am willing to write a recursive function to fetch large groups, but there must be a shorter and direct way)

Comment: Have you checked each step in the pipeline returns the correct output? Start by commenting out everything after the first `|`, then the second, then the third, etc. It'll give you insight into what's wrong.

Comment: nothing. If i just go with Get-ADGroup -Identity "DEPT_120_SA" -server "mhf.mhc" -Properties * , it gives me a list of users and groups. i cannot reiterate further into these groups using -recursive. while this happens when i use get-adgroupmember.

Comment: Are you completely sure this group has subgroups? It seems strange that `-recurse` does not work. However, I just realised this: `Get-ADGroupMember` already returns ADUsers, so there is no need to use `Get-ADUser` afterwards. How would adding `-properties mail` and the `select SAMAccountName...` etc work directly after `Get-ADGroupMember`?

Comment: Get-ADGroupmember is not my concern here. i am sure that can be refined into a shorter code snippet.
Get-ADGroup yes is not working with -recursive, and my group indeed has child groups.

Comment: Get-ADGroup returns a group, and not users, so why are you pipelining it to Get-ADUser? This will not work, instead, just use Get-ADGroupmember. Am I misunderstanding?

Comment: Made a little code edit to avoid this confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 5000 limit applies only to `Get-ADGroupMembers` not `Get-ADUsers`, so we can use the LDAP_MATCHING_RULE_IN_CHAIN matching rule `(OID 1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941)`.

For example:

```
Get-AdUser -LdapFilter "(memberOf:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=cn=group,cn=users,DC=ad,DC=local)"
```

where `cn=group,cn=users,DC=ad,DC=local` is the distinguished name of the group you want members for.